# oracle select rows where one column depends on two values in second column

Tags: oracle

I have data with users bidding for items (lets say sorted by time asc):

```
item_id, win, user_id
------------------
1, 0, 1
1, 0, 2
1, 1, 1
2, 0, 3
2, 0, 4
2, 1, 3
```

I need to select only these users, who lost in bidding for an item. So for the item_id = 1: user nr 1 lost because user nr 2 bidded higher and then user nr 2 lost too because user nr 1 bidded higher. For this item SELECT should return user_id = 2.

How can I select all such users in a smart way?

Comment: `I need to select only these users, who lost in bidding for an item` So, If 10 user bidded, and 9 lost bidding, then you need select all of these 9 users ?

Comment: Yes. Except for these who lost, but won finally (this is hard)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT   item_id, user_id
FROM     your_table
GROUP BY item_id, user_id
HAVING   MAX( win ) = 0;
```

Comment: Very good and clean solution. The answer would have been better though with a brief explanation instead of a mere query.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner - I agree with you in the general case; but in this special instance, the solution is such a basic SQL statement, no explanation should be needed. SO is not the place to learn/teach the first two days' worth of basic SQL.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I normally would but there is no need to use anything other than the simplest `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clauses for this so any text is going to just say "You could `GROUP BY` the columns and use `HAVING` to restrict it to those who haven't won." Its just duplicating what this simple query says instead using English sentences and does not add anything to the solution that can't be seen by a quick perusal of the code - so it got left out.

Comment: This solution is smart, thank you! Actually I thought that HAVING clause affects the result at the end of the query. And there is no "win" value until HAVING, so how can this work? Thank you, if you can explain.

Comment: @bry888 You state in the question that there are three columns `item_id`, `win` and `user_id`. What do you mean by asking "there is no "win" value until HAVING, so how can this work?"? You specified a `win` column in the question.

Comment: Sorry, I mean in this query:

SELECT   item_id, user_id
FROM     your_table
GROUP BY item_id, user_id
HAVING   MAX( win ) = 0;
I thought that this: HAVING   MAX( win ) = 0;
Works on the result of:
SELECT   item_id, user_id
FROM     your_table
GROUP BY item_id, user_id
But the above result has no win column, only item_id, user_id - so how HAVING   MAX( win ) = 0 can find the value of MAX(win)?
I hope, I asked clearer now :)

Comment: @bry888 When processing the `SELECT`, `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clauses no column in the table is discarded, including the `win` column (even though it is not in the list of columns `SELECT`ed); so you can still access its values.

Answer (score 0):

Change here "bids" with your table name

```
select  t.item_id, t.user_id  from (
    select item_id, user_id 
    from bids
    group by item_id, user_id 
) t
left join (select item_id, user_id from   bids   where win = 1 ) winners
ON
t.item_id = winners.item_id
AND
t.user_id = winners.user_id
WHERE 
winners.item_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Too complicated and inefficient for such a simple problem.

Comment: I tried this one and it looks reasonable/gives nice results. I'll test it more tomorrow